# Does Project Lombok work well with Scala?

Tags: eclipse, scala, lombok

If I wanted my Scala project to be "compatible" with Java, that is make it practical to call the Scala API from Java code (so that non-Scala programmers can also contribute), would it be possible to use Project Lombok in the Java code? Or do the two of them don't get along well?

I would be developing in Eclipse with the Scala IDE.

EDIT: What I really meant was: will the Scala *editor* in Eclipse see the code generated by Lombok, or just the Java code I really typed?

Comment: Concerning your edit and my complete lack of knowledge about Eclipse - what will work obviously is when you are using your compiled Java code as a library. So your question is only interesting for mixed projects, not mixing libraries.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are asking, since Scala and Java are inter-operation in bytecode level, it doesn't care where the bytecode come from. So I believe your Java code which use Lombok annotation is still could be called from Scala program.

And if you are asking if those annotation Lombok provide could be used in Scala code, I see no point, because most of those feature are provided by Scala itsef.

For example,a class with `@Data` could be a `case class` in Scala.

```
case class Data(name: String, value: Int)
```

And you could access it in Java code just like an normal class.

```
Data d1 = new Data("someData", 1);  // Using constructor
Data d2 = Data.apply("someData", 1); // Or using factory
```

And `Data` will have all wonderful `toString`, `equals`, `hashcode`....etc.

Comment: +1 I wasn't thinking about it this way, but it does answer half my question. I'll specify what I want by editing the question.

Comment: Actually, I should have thought of that myself before asking. Bad question.

Comment: I think I found a use case where I actually would prefer lombok to case classes. Creating an object with the @Builder annotation is much more readable than a case class. Wonder if there's anything in scala that allows to do this easily

Answer (score 13):

The scala editor part will 'see' the generated code just fine.

Most of what lombok does follows some spec or other, same as scala. Where lombok deviates is canEqual and equals implementations, which incidentally is the *exact* same thing scala generates for case classes IIRC, so even that is compatible :)

DISCLAIMER: I'm a core contributor to project lombok.

Comment: Hmm, I'm currently having issues with my scala-test code not finding my constructor generated by @RequiredArgsConstructor. Wondering if that's an issue in my setup or a bug.

Comment: Just solved it, it was a problem with Eclipse compiling Scala code before Java code, to change it:
Preferences >> Scala >> Compiler >> BuildManager Tab >> Change compileOrder from Mixed to JavaThenScala

Comment: @rzwitserloot In situations where Scala case classes have `@Data` annotation on them, would you recommend using Javac over Eclipsec for compilation of such code?

Comment: @rzwitserloot having issues with the lombok `@Log4j2` annotation in scala, i don't seem to get a `log` variable in the scala code...

Comment: @Jewels the log annotation makes a private variable in java code. It would be impossible to see it from scala code and that is by design.